# Name of Band and Title of Song do not display in push notifications

Tags: java, android, audio-player

So I have this code and it works fine in my notifications. But the correct song does not display.

My ("Standard Title") and ("songTitle") test works fine with the dummy data. But the actual song data does not display like ("Metallica") or ("Master Of Puppets"). I have files in my raw folder and the songs play fine but when the app runs, the correct (name of the band) and the (song title)do not show.

My question is; should I create and xml file that will hold that information? or Perhaps a set of Strings in the values folder?

I appreciate your help.

```
// Notification Manager
    NotificationManager mgr = 
            (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Setting the default action.
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = 
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, REQUEST_NOTIFY_LAUNCH, intent, 0);
    // Setting the default action.
    builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    builder.setContentTitle("Standard Title");
    builder.setContentText("songTitle");
    mgr.notify(STANDARD_NOTIFICATION, builder.build());

    }
```

Comment: How you fetch artist name and song name?

Comment: As per your post, i understood that, you are not updating notification when song got changed. write one broadcast for that and update your notification.

Comment: Yes. Notification does not update with the current song name and title. Writing a broadcast will help me beth this data? So i don't need to write a string file? Thank you Leena. 

I have not achieved that aril_123. I am trying to find out what I have to do to get there :)

Comment: Please, attach the code used to update the notification. You need to push a new Notification with updated data using the same NotificationID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do NOT declare band and song names in a string file. This is really bad practice. What happens if you play a song that's not in your string file? How big will the file get? Instead, get that information from the music file itself.

You'll want to use a `MediaMetadataRetriever`, use something like this when a new song starts playing.

Here is an example of getting the title from an mp3 file:

`MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(mp3File);
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(yourContext, uri);
String title = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);`

Also take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html